# Exporting Excel data as CSV with VBA does not export correct file type and cell values

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have an Excel file which should have the following functionality:

User selects a range and clicks the export button, this should generate a CSV file with a specific title including the date, like "annual_25.03.2022" with the cells holding the values only, as in the Excel file, the cells all have formulas.

playerNr  |  amount  |   reason    |  expireDate         |  ProductType  |   ProductItem

13661748  |   100    | ANNIVERSARY | 2022-04-19T23:59:00 |All            |  All

All of the rows have formulas behind them. The problems I am encountering are:

- The first two rows playerNr and amount are not exported as values, but the formula behind the cells.
- The created file does not have the desired name, it's just the standard format(new book)
- The created file has the Excel extension instead of CSV
- The export button is on the new file too, even though I do not select it, I would like to delete that on the new file, the export button should only be on the Excel template.

The VBA looks like this:

```
Sub ExportSelectedData()


ActiveSheet.Unprotect



Dim Rng As Range

Dim WorkRng As Range

Dim xFile As Variant

Dim xFileString As String

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Check your selection"

 Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Application.ActiveSheet.Copy

Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

'Application.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xFileString = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Anniversaries " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), filefilter:="Comma Separated Text (*.CSV), *.CSV")

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveSheet.Protect



End Sub
```

So I am not sure how to paste only the values and why the string for the new file is wrong, I have tried various approaches and none of them worked.

Also, I have no idea why the export button remains on the new file, and the sheet protection seems to work only randomly.

After the suggestions, I have ran the following code:

```
Sub ExportSelectedData()

Dim Rng As Range

Dim WorkRng As Range

Dim xFile As Variant

Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Unprotect

Dim xFileString As StringOn Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Check your selection"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes: sh.Delete: Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(WorkRng.rows.count, WorkRng.Columns.count).value = WorkRng.value

ws.Protect

Set xFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xFileString = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Anniversaries " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), filefilter:="Comma Separated Text (*.CSV), *.CSV")

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Debug.Print xFileString:Stop



End Sub
```

The debug shows "" in immediate window, there is no new file generated with the above.

Comment: Try copying in a different way, which will be even faster for larger ranges, not using clipboard. Instead of `WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` try using `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(WorkRng.rows.count, WorkRng.Columns.count).value = WorkRng.value`.

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks for that, so this should automatically paste the values into the new sheet? I am coming from other languages and struggling to see which part copies/selects and which pastes.

Comment: @FaneDuru I suppose with your approach I can leave out these 2 lines? >>Application.ActiveSheet.Copy

Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
and simply replace the >> WorkRng.Copy Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
 with your line of code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Your code (now) creates a new workbook with the content of the `ActiveSheet` (with the line `ActiveSheet.Copy`), clears its content and copy starting from "A1" the previously selected range, only the cells value. And you may renounce of all the time using `Application`. Excel guesses what you try doing without it, too. It is necessary only in some cases. In none of the ones you try in the above code...

Comment: @FaneDuru , so the ActiveSheet.Copy bit is already referring to the new sheet? Why does this copy the macro button into the new file? I have not tried your code yet, maybe this would be solved and leave me with the removal of the macro button and how to get the proper file extension and name..

Comment: That would explain that the initial unprotect sheet line works, but the last protect sheet does not work

Comment: It practically creates a new **workbook** with a single sheet, **containing everything existent in the former `ActiveSheet`**.  I forgot about the buton. You should also specifically delete the shapes. Please, use the next code line (one line): `For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes: sh.Delete: Next`. About protection, the newly active sheet is not the former one....

Comment: In order to protect the initial active sheet you should create a variable to keep it as object. `Dim ws as Worksheet` `Set ws = ActiveSheet`. Then use `ws.Unprotect` and `ws.Protect` at the end...

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks, if this works, this deserves three times correct answer. So, just to clarify, after which line am I supposed to delete the button and to protect the original sheet, the ws protect can be just before end sub or does it have to be further up?

Comment: And what am I doing wrong with the new sheet generation code, it generates an excel file instead of a CSV.

Comment: It should generate a CSV file. I tested your code and it generate a csv file. Try `Debug.Print xFileString:Stop` before the saving line. What does it return in Immediate Window when the code stops? You may protect anywhere, but **after copying the necessary range value**. It may stay where it is now, too...

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks, does it generate a CSV with the desired name for you? Mine just gets the name "book{index}" pattern, standard unnamed output.

Comment: Yes, it does, but I my confess I cannot understand too much from your last comment... Please, copy from `Immediate Window` and paste here the returned string. I do not see what to be confidential... Doesn't it end in `.CSV`?

Comment: Will do a bit later when back on the machine, I was just saying that for me it appeared to generate a file with this name> book1.xlsm . Could this be because I am using a Mac?

Comment: Are you using the above code, only modified as I recommended? Please, try editing your question and paste there the code you actually use. You maybe made a mistake during modications. Of course, when the code availability...

Comment: Ok will post the modified code and results, but it will take me two hours until I get home.

Comment: I do not have a problem with that... If I will find some time, I will maybe post an answer with a piece of working code.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have updated the running code in the question, immediate window shows "" and there is no file generated, not sure what is wrong, would be appreciated if you can check, thanks

Comment: Did you check the code I posted? Does the dialog show? If yes, do you click Cancel?

Comment: I am driving...

Comment: Only the first dialog shows, if no cells are selected. The debug line just halts the execution and no dialog is shows, the "console" shows the state of the variables, for file name it shows empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code, which should be working as (I understood) you need:

```
Sub ExportSelectedData()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, shP As Shape
 Dim WorkRng As Range, xFileString As String, xTitleId As String
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet: ws.Unprotect

 xTitleId = "Please, select the range to place it in the .CSV document!"

 Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, , Type:=8)
 ws.Copy 'create a workbook containing the former active sheet
 Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 sh.cells.Clear 'clear the content of the newly created workbook, active sheet
 For Each shP In ActiveSheet.Shapes: shP.Delete: Next 'delete all existing sheets

 'copy the necessary range as value:
 sh.Range("A1").Resize(WorkRng.rows.count, WorkRng.Columns.count).value = WorkRng.value

 'choose the folder where to save the csv and build its name:
 xFileString = GetFolderPath(ThisWorkbook.path)
 xFileString = xFileString & Application.PathSeparator & "Anniversaries " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".CSV"
 Debug.Print xFileString: Stop 'check if the path has been correctly built. If yes, press F5

 'save the active document using the above settled name:
 ActiveWorkbook.saveas fileName:=xFileString, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=False, CreateBackup:=False
 'ActiveWorkbook.close False 'uncomment this line after confirmation that it works as you need...
 ws.Protect
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

For using the code on MAC, please try the next function giving the possibility to select folder and returning its path:

```
Private Function GetFolderPath(Optional strPath As String) As String
Dim Fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
 Set Fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 With Fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder to build the SaveAs name!"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If strPath <> "" Then .InitialFileName = strPath 'the folder where the dialog to open
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With
NextCode:
 GetFolderPath = sItem
 Set Fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testGetFldPath()
  Dim foldPath As String
    foldPath = GetFolderPath(ThisWorkbook.path)
    foldPath = foldPath & Application.PathSeparator & "Anniversaries " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".CSV"
    Debug.Print foldPath
End Sub
```

I will adapt the initial code to use it.

Comment: @ptts I thought I posted this answer some hours before. It looks I did not have internet connection... I found it now and posted. Please, check it and we will talk about your problem only if it does no t work as you need.

Comment: thanks, I was confused initially, I have run this now, but this line >  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, , Type:=8)
gives me a run-time error 424 Object required.
Debug mode shows sh, shP,WorkRng as value nothing, sfilestring as empty string andxTitleId is ok.

Comment: @ptts Did you select a range **in the active sheet**?

Comment: yes I did, I tried to just select it and to select then CTRL+C, both lead to the same result

Comment: I just seen that there might be a comma too many here >>  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, , Type:=8) < after xTitleId, changing that and closing some other files helped, now the new file is generated, the values are perfect, but I get run time error 1004, method getSaveAsFilename of object '_Application' failed

Comment: the odd thing is, running it again, it fails before creating a new sheet with the same 1004 error. But we are very close to the solution

Comment: I found the reason for this error, its MAC specific, but I need this for a team using MACs >> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/84a8567f-0468-4551-890b-05aea34b6c4b/excel-vba-getopenfilename-method-not-working-on-a-mac?forum=exceldev   and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/hh710200(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN Now I am not sure how to implement that

Comment: @ptts I do not have a MAC to test... I would propose to renounce at this way of building the path. I will post a function able to return a (selected) folder path and the code will concatenate the string part with it and csv extension.

Comment: yes please, if you do not mind, I have found a "poly-fill" for MAC and will try that as well.

Comment: @ptts Please, test the updated code. Do not forget to copy the function after the modified code. Now it is late in my country and I have to close my laptop. I will be available tomorrow. Have a good night!

Comment: late here too, please leave the first code in there as well, it is at least a working windows os solution. I need to know where to put that private function and what I need to remove from the windows code

Comment: @ptts The adapted code should work in both cases. You only have to use the adapted code and copy the function near/below it... The testing `Sub` was only supplied to preliminarily visually check that it works as you need.

Comment: so I can just drop that bit somewhere before the lines where the new document is created? Will report later how it went thanks man

Comment: @ptts You have only to copy the updated code (function included) and run the code. Take care to not have a Sub with the same name. Modify the existing one as `ExportSelectedData_Init`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243889/discussion-between-ptts-and-faneduru).